# ChartJS com PHP

Tags: php, chartjs

Opa, estou usando o  [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org) para geração de gráficos, estou integrando com PHP para envio de json ao gráfico

php

```
$arrLabels = array("January","February","March");
$arrDatasets = array('label' => "My First dataset",'fillColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)", 'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff", 'pointHighlightFill' => "#fff", 'pointHighlightStroke' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 'data' => array('28', '48', '40'));

$arrReturn = array(array('labels' => $arrLabels, 'datasets' => $arrDatasets));

print (json_encode($arrReturn));
```

js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("salesChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        data_retorno
    }
});
```

Valor de `data_retorno`

```
[  
   {  
      "labels":[  
         "January",
         "February",
         "March"
      ],
      "datasets":{  
         "label":"My First dataset",
         "fillColor":"rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
         "strokeColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)",
         "pointColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)",
         "pointStrokeColor":"#fff",
         "pointHighlightFill":"#fff",
         "pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(220,220,220,1)",
         "data":[  
            "28",
            "48",
            "40"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Onde `data_retorno` é o retorno do ajax.

O gráfico que já está carregado com outros dados, ao receber este resultado, simplesmente as linhas desaparecem e não acontece nada

Comment: Talvez o `data_retorno` não está no formato que o chartjs espera. Pode compartilhar conosco o valor de `data_retorno`?

Comment: Opa @LucasCosta editei a pergunta adicionando o valor de `data_retorno`, vlw

Comment: tente `data: data_retorno[0]` @sNniffer

Comment: @LucasCosta deu erro Chart.js, erro:`TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new String(" ")): not an object`

Answer (score 0):

O formato dos dados do retorno tem dois detalhes que precisam se adeguar ao *charjs*, que são:

- a propriedade `data` espera um objeto ao invés de um array
- a propriedade `datasets` espera um array ao invés de um objeto

Partindo do princípio que seu retorno é esse, podemos adequar o `data_retorno` dessa forma:

```
var data_retorno = [...] // ... indica todo o conteúdo
data_retorno = data_retorno[0]; // pega o objeto dentro do array
data_retorno.datasets = [].concat(data_retorno.datasets); // cria um array como valor
```

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wwrtynec/2/**

Comment: Eu justamente converti o dataset para array @sNniffer, você pode verificar se ele já é um array, se for não usar a conversão `[].concat`..